# Getting all id's from one table in database that aren't in another table in another database using posgres and php

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1, and I have two databases with one table names clients that are identical and contain +-50k rows each.

I need to obtain all ids in one table that aren't in the other, I have the following solution

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM clients WHERE id NOT IN(".pg_query($conn1,'SELECT id FROM clients').")";
$result = pg_query($conn2,$sql);
```

Before I run this, is this a good way to do it via PHP or are the other better faster ways?

Unfortunately I cant use dblink since I do not have privileges to install it.

Comment: uh, you're selecting from the same table in both queries. even if this code would work (it won't ever), you'll never get an answer when you're saying "give me the list of all people whose name is fred, in the list of people whose name ISN'T fred"

Comment: @Marc, the broader picture is this, I need to get all the id's so that I know which rows to import to the db table that needs to be sync with the other table, so that I can only insert the latest

Comment: @MarcB: You may be missing the point where the second instance of `clients` is supposed to live in another database. Your comment does not apply.

Comment: @MarcB - The one client table resides in a different db than the other clients table

Comment: -1 for incomplete question. If you are using the very outdated version PostgreSQL 8.1 you **have to** mention that up front. That's the bare minimum. You have been member of this forum long enough to know better. Any programmer should know better.

Comment: -1 Failed to mention ancient version, unclear question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a database link I think you will have to do it in the middleware - and this middleware should have a lot of RAM.

I would also recommend not to use PHP for this purpose, but if you have no other possibility, I would do it like this:

```
$ids = array();
$idsNotExist = array();
$resultDb1 = pg_query('SELECT id FROM db1');
while ( $row = pg_fetch_dontknowtheexactfunction_row($resultDb1) ) {
  array_push($ids, $row['id']);
}

$resultDb2 = pg_query('SELECT id FROM db2');
while ( $row = pg_fetch($resultDb2) ) {
  if ( !in_array($ids, $row['id']) ) {
    array_push($idsNotExist, $row['id']);
  }
}
```

Best way would of course be, because ID is primary key, to write an own in_array-function which removes the ID from haystack when it's found because it will not be searched for again and the next search loop will be a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

#### dblink

You can make use of [**dblink**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink-function.html) to refer to tables from another database in your query.

Then your query could look like this (one of multiple different approaches):

```
SELECT id
FROM   clients c
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM   dblink('dbname=mydb', 'SELECT id FROM clients')
    AS     c(id int)
    )  x USING (id)
WHERE  x.id IS NULL;
```

Since PostgreSQL 9.1 [installing an additional module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createextension.html) has become even simpler:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

Run once per database. As for [the necessary privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createextension.html):

> Loading an extension requires the same privileges that would be
>   required to create its component objects. For most extensions this
>   means superuser or database owner privileges are needed.

#### COPY

If dblink (or similar x-db tools are not available for you, try [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) TO / FROM to transfer contents of the foreign table:

In foreign db:

```
COPY clients TO '/path/to/file';
```

In home db:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE c_tmp (LIKE clients);
COPY c_tmp FROM '/path/to/file';

SELECT id
FROM   clients c
LEFT   JOIN c_tmp x USING (id)
WHERE  x.id IS NULL;
```

Temp. table is dropped automatically at end of session.

Comment: I had a look at dblink, but can't use it, it's not installed on server, and to get it installed could take months, due to procedures, are the no other ways

Comment: Thanx, seems simplistic, but running postgres 8.1 still

Comment: @Roland: This may be simpler than think. Added a bit to my answer. also added a fallback solution. But first, upgrade do a more recent version. [PostgreSQL 8.1 is long dead and forgotten - EOL Nov. 2010!](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Still, it would be easy to install dblink, even in Postgres 8.1. Check the manual. And next time, **mention your version before you send me on a wild goose chase**. That's just disrespecting the time of people trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM db.clients
WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM otherdb.clients
)
```

one single query. There's no need for multiple db connections, unless the user ID you used for the first connection doesn't have access rights on one of those tables. SQL allows fully absolute `db.table.field` type specifications to allow cross-db queries.

Comment: Now you are missing that you cannot address tables in other dbs like that in PostgreSQL.

Comment: ah. bleah. yay postgres. in that case, you'll have to do a fullblow query/fetch sequence, build an `x,y,z,a,b,c,....` list of ids string, then insert that into the other query.